# Blend 3 Can't Open VS 2010 Projects!

Tags: visual-studio, expression-blend-3, visual-studio-2010

I have Blend 3 Final and Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1 installed and I need to develop in VS 2010 with .net 4.0 and design my end-user UI in Blend but Blend 3 can't open my projects!
What should I do?! :((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm running Blend 3 + SketchFlow (build 3.0.1927) and Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 (build 10.0.21006.1) and that combination works just fine. I get a warning that Blend 3 might not be able to open the VS10 solution, but I get no problem opening it here. *Works on My Machine* certified :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to download and istall Microsoft Expression Blend Preview for .NET 4 and then you will be able to open VS2010 beta 2 projects and solutions.

At lease until the full version comes out.

here is the download link:
[Microsoft Expression Blend Preview for .NET 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6806e466-dd25-482b-a9b3-3f93d2599699&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that Blend 3 supports Visual Studio 2010 projects.  This is common given that Blend 3 is a RTM product and Visual Studio 2010 is still in Beta.  I'm not sure what the plan is for Blend and supporting Visual Studio 2010 solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Blend 3 doesn't support Visual Studio 2010 projects that target .NET 4.0. If you want to use Blend for those, you need to download the Blend preview at the link Roboblob provided.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the changes to the solution file

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

to 
    Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
    # Visual Studio 2008

And then make the changes to the project file

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to

v3.5

and

```
<RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
```

to
    3.5

Craig

Answer (score 0):

Well, Kjetil is right. But if you want to change your solution back to VS2008, all you have to do is, open your solution file (.sln) in a text editor and change the first two lines from:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

to

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
```

As of now (Beta 2), that is the only change which VS2010 makes to your solution file. You can switch between the two versions without worrying too much about compatibility of the solution files.

Comment: But you know?! They won't still open .net 4.0 Solutions!!! And that's driving me nuts! :( :((